# How can I convert the epoch time to YMD in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to convert a date from epoch to year month day and get the correct date.

```
my $day = 18322;
my ($y, $m, $d) = (gmtime 86400*$day)[5,4,3];
```

The epoch date is `1583020800` The conversion is as follows `$y is 120 $m is 2 $d is 1`
I guess I have to add `$y = $y+1900` I get the correct year, I can add 1 to `$m` to get the correct month the day `$d` I don't have to add anything to.  Is this correct.  I am taking over code for someone but I have no idea what `[5,4,3]` does.

Comment: Are you starting from day 18322? Or epoch 1583020800?

Comment: "what [5,4,3] does" is extracting only the wanted parts from an array. Since `gmtime` returns an array, the parentheses around it allow you to directly use the `[5,4,3]` notation to get only the elements you want: 5, 4 and 3. See `perldoc -f localtime` or [this link](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) for details about that gmtime/localtime array.

Comment: for what timezone do you want the date for that epoch time?

Answer (score 4):

Epoch time 1583020800 is Sun Mar 1 00:00:00 2020.

You can use `gmtime`, but it's awkward. It returns an array of values and they need to be converted. The year is the number of years since 1900 and the month starts at 0. This is because it is a thin wrapper around [`struct tm` from the C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) Perl is written in.

```
my($y,$m,$d) = (gmtime(1583020800))[5,4,3];
$y += 1900;
$m += 1;
printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", $y, $m, $d;
```

Instead, use the built in [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).

```
use v5.10;

use Time::Piece;
my $time = Time::Piece->gmtime(1583020800);
say $time->ymd;
```

Or the more powerful [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).

```
use v5.10;

use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => 1583020800);
say $dt->ymd;
```

Comment: If converting to YMD is the task, DateTime really doesn't have an advantage there. It's good for doing tricky Date math involving all the arcane details that entails. Schwern knows this, but most people don't.

Answer (score 3):

The `(...)[5,4,3]` is a literal list slice. The thing inside the parens creates a list, but this selects only elements 5, 4, and 3.

The `gmtime` docs point to [localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html), which shows you the position of each thing in its list:

```
localtime
        Converts a time as returned by the time function to a 9-element
        list with the time analyzed for the local time zone. Typically
        used as follows:

            #     0    1    2     3     4    5     6     7     8
            my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
                                                        localtime(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Time::Piece as in Schwern's answer. But just to cover all bases, you can use the `strftime()` function from POSIX.pm as well.

```
use feature 'say';
use POSIX qw[strftime];

say strftime('%Y-%m-%d', gmtime(1583020800));
```

Output:

```
2020-03-01
```

You can pass different format strings to `strftime()`.